# Load-once config by merging/updating properties onto module's namespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, namespaces, python-module

Take the following config singleton class in Python:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function
from builtins import *
import sys

class Config(object):

    __instance = None

    def __new__(cls):
        if cls.__instance is None:
            cls.__instance = super(Config, cls).__new__(cls)
            cls.__instance.__initialized = False
        return cls.__instance

    def __init__(self):
        print('INIT')
        if self.__initialized: 
            return
        self.__initialized = True

        self._defaults = {"foo": True, "bar": False}

        for k, v in self._defaults.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

    def reload(self):
        print(self)
        if not self._defaults:
            return
        for k, v in self._defaults.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
```

I can write a test that validates that properties set and update properly:

```
import config; config = config.Config()

print(config)
print(config.foo)
assert(config.foo is True)
config.foo = False
print(config.foo)
assert(config.foo is False)

config.reload()
print(config.foo)
assert(config.foo is True)
```

Outputs:

```
INIT
<config.Config object at 0x10bbf73d0>
True
False
<config.Config object at 0x10bbf73d0>
True
```

This works OK, but my OCD can't handle that I have to import config and execute its main class.

I tried adding `sys.modules[__name__] = Config()` to the bottom of `config.py`, so that I can do just `import config`, but it balks on `reload()` with:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Oddly I'd only expected it to complain that the values aren't being updated on the modules namespace, but it appears to be breaking beforehand - just trying to execute `reload()`.

Am I out of luck here? Or is there some magical way I can this to work both with `reload()` and a one-liner `import config`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work when you `reload` is because after assigning to `sys.modules[__name__]`, the module, along with its builtins, get garbage collected and replaced with `None`. I'm assuming you know this, since you `from builtins import *`. However, the imported builtins will also be garbage collected.

To fix this, you can import builtins inside `reload`, so that you are using versions that don't get garbage collected.

Side note: This is untested, since I cannot reproduce your problem [here](https://repl.it/@pyelias/Test), but I trust that it happens since that site can be wonky when it comes to imports.

Comment: Ahh, importing it *after* I overwrite the module works!